# ( ) => in addEventListener wont be executed

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to `JavaScript` and I struggle extending existing code of my coworker.

What I try to achieve:

1. Get all images with `id = yt`
2. add an `EventListener` to all
3. `Call method` to replace the image depending on the event error target

I already implemented to logic, an this code works:

```
export class ImageYt{
    
    initialize() {
        var yt = document.querySelectorAll('#yt');

        for (var i = 0; i < yt.length;  i++) {
            yt[i].addEventListener('error', this.setThumbnail(yt[i]));
        }
    }

    setThumbnail(yt){
        yt.setAttribute('src', 'placeholder');
    }

}
```

But I would like to extend the EventListener with an event (to use it later) like this:

```
yt[i].addEventListener('error', (event) => this.setThumbnail(yt[i]));
```

But then my code is not working and the method `setThumbnail` wont be called anymore. I asume it has something to do with `( ) =>`. I had a look on different documentations and this type of function call is limited, maybe the problem is that I call the `addEventListener` multiple times?
I know `this` will be inherited from the declaring scope but tbh I don't understand the mechanic enough to have a proper soultion.

Comment: use function if you want to use `this` but instead delegate

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#yt');`? "Ids must be unique". And the problem you are facing is probably that the error event doesn't fire. What are these elements?

Comment: Not sure, but by reading this quickly, since the lexical scope with the arrow function is pointing to the variable as is, and not at the time of creation, it will always look at the latest rendition of 'i' ?

Comment: You are instantiating the class object in your code right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. IDs need to be unique so `document.querySelectorAll('#yt');` may work but is very much not recommended
2. Use function if you want to use `this` - arrow functions do not have `this`
3. `addEventListener('error', this.setThumbnail(yt[i]))` would not add an event listener but instead add the result of the setThumbnail which is not a function

This works - I am using a class

```js
const imageList = document.querySelectorAll('.imgError');
imageList.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('error', function() { // here you can use this
    this.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-24.png')
}));
// trigger the error
imageList.forEach(img => img.src = "does not exist")
```

```html
<img class="imgError" />
<img class="imgError" />
<img class="imgError" />
<img class="imgError" />
<img class="imgError" />
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#yt');` will actually work, it's very bad code, but this will work...

Comment: @Kaiido It shouldn't

Comment: I used the ``querySelectorAll`` because I have multiple target images on my site and during my development I discovered the problem that only one image was effected. I try to figure out a better solution for this

Comment: @mplungjan  why should `querySelectorAll` care about what type of selector you pass? Meaning, why should it not do what it's supposed to do, just because the selector happens to be something that should only ever select one element? I mean, I do understand what you're saying, though I think it's to last thing to worry about here. And actually (IMO) it isn't all that bad to use here. It enables the selector to be extracted later without further code changes.

Comment: I totally agree! But what I'm saying is, why should `querySelectorAll` care about that?

Comment: @Rendolph I made some working code. It seems one cannot delegate the load error.

Answer (score 1):

Your original implementation is already problematic, because it executes `this.setThumbnail()` immediately when the event listener is defined (not when the error event is fired). It sounds like this is what you intend to do:

```
export class ImageYt{

  initialize() {
    var yt = document.querySelectorAll('#yt');

    for (var i = 0; i < yt.length;  i++) {
        // Set thumbnail at runtime
        this.setThumbnail(yt[i]);

        yt[i].addEventListener('error', () => {
          // Logic to be executed when error event is fired here
        });
    }
  }

  setThumbnail(yt){
    yt.setAttribute('src', 'placeholder');
  }

}
```

Comment: This seems good to me, not sure about that ID thing

Comment: To my horror I see that `document.querySelectorAll('#yt')` actually would work. It is VERY much not recommended to have non-unique IDs

Comment: I used the ``querySelectorAll`` because I have multiple target images on my site and during my development I discovered the problem that only one image was effected. I try to figure out a better solution for this

Comment: @Rendolph If you have multiple elements with the id `yt`, only the first one will be selected.